# how to hide images i want but be unhidden when needed in isotope

Tags: jquery, html, css

so i have a library of different images on my site coded with isotope, the question is this how to hide images i want but be unhidden when needed, i have succeeded in "show all" list with "not(.new, .black)"code  and so but before the user click on the show all there are all images showed without any filtering my code:

```
   <div class="container">
           <section>
               <ul class="portfolio_filters"></a>
                     <li><a href="#" data-filter=":not(.new,.black,industrial,.mix).all">Show all</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" data-filter=".new">New Logos</a></li>                                  <!--lightbox2-->
                     <li><a href="#" data-filter=".black ">Black & White</a></li>                            <!--lightbox3-->
                     <li><a href="#" data-filter=".industrial">Industrial</a></li>                            <!--lightbox3-->
                     <li><a href="#" data-filter=".mix">Mix</a></li>                                           <!--lightbox4-->
                </ul>
           </section>
```

Image link

```
            <section class="portfolio_masonry"  >

                <div class="row isotope_portfolio_container">

                   <div class="new col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                          <div class="portfolio_item"> <a href="images/portfolio/lenses.jpg" class="lightbox"  >  <img src="images/portfolio/lenses.jpg"  alt="Community & Non-Profit" >
                               <div class="overlay">
                                    <div class="desc">
                                         <h4>Lenses to Their World</h4>
                                         <span class="cross"></span> </div></a>
                               </div>
                               </a> </div>
                     </div>
```

here my isotopes code

```
//------ISOTOPE-------------------------------------    

// cache container
var container = jQuery('.isotope_portfolio_container');
// initialize isotope
 container.isotope({
});
jQuery('.portfolio_filters a[data-filter="*"]').addClass('active');
// filter items when filter link is clicked
jQuery('.portfolio_filters a').click(function(){
  jQuery('.portfolio_filters a').removeClass('active');
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
  var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
  container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});
```

how to make some images hidden in the start page without clicking on one of the lists and those images to be viewable on the lists i want , thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the Isotope demo? http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nFrte

Comment: The isotope code you added above has an extra `});` after the line `container.isotope({filter: '.new'});` not sure if this is because you've selected part, but not all of your code, or if it's an error

Comment: yes i made it from the answer "mathf" told me and first it dident work than i updatet it here with that error...

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: yes the mistake was exactly that part i took the answer from "mathf" ,thank you for you help , after i uploaded my isotope code i saw that and fixed it , yet its working just fine.

Comment: If you ever need to see if your js code is valid, go to http://www.jsfiddle.net and paste your code in the JS section, add the appropriate library and click on "JSHint" at the top of the page. It will put a red dot beside the line that causes an error and give you a hint at what it is. There are other ways of doing this, however I find this to be the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want to initially hide some images when page is loaded, and show them when start filtering or showing all by filter navigation?

Try to add .invis class to your element containing your image and information

ex.

```
<div class="new col-sm-4 col-md-4 invis">
```

Comment: yes your understood right , but i tried with invis class but not succeeded it doesn't hide any of my images ;s thanks between

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Filtering (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html). Adding a filter will only show items with the ".new" class on startup, for example.

```
$container.isotope({ filter: '.new' });
```

Comment: thanks for you answer yes i looked over that page, i just edited my post yet you can see my isotope code there may that help , thanks again .

Comment: yes it worked thank you very much my friend i was searching for the right answer like a week or so thank you and have a good day.